# Unable to find chrome binary in WSL while running Rails tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-chromedriver, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run integration tests for my Rails application in Windows Subsystem for Linux. I have downloaded the `chromedriver` file for windows from the official site and placed it in `Documents/bin` folder. I have added the following file in the same folder and saved it as `chromedriver`:

```
#!/bin/sh
chromedriver.exe "$@"
```

So presently `Documents/bin` folder has these two files: `chromedriver.exe` and `chromedriver`. I have added this folder to `PATH` in windows.
When I type `chromedriver -v` in Ubuntu terminal in Windows I get the following output:

```
ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90 (a6dcaf7e3ec6f70a194cc25e8149475c6590e025-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1003})
```

But when I execute any Rails integration test I am getting the following error:

```
sh: 1: ["/usr/local/sbin", "/usr/local/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/bin", "/sbin", "/bin", "/opt/google/chrome"]: not found 
sh: 1: ["/usr/local/sbin", "/usr/local/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/bin", "/sbin", "/bin", "/opt/google/chrome"]: not found 
sh: 1: ["/usr/local/sbin", "/usr/local/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/bin", "/sbin", "/bin", "/opt/google/chrome"]: not found 

Webdrivers::VersionError: Failed to find Chrome binary or its version.
```

chrome version in windows: `Version 75.0.3770.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

So linux is able to find chromedriver but not rails. How can I rectify this error? Should I run `sudo apt-get install chromium chrome-driver`? Or is there another method to make rails know the path to chromedriver binary?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path to your chrome.exe to the PATH environment variable in Ubuntu